# How to display tableau dashboard in Django?

Tags: django, tableau-api

I want to embedded Tableau dashboard result into one of the html pages in Django. Can it be done?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

there are several methods, however i am writing the one which i am using.

**Tableau Embed Code**

**Step 1 :** On your Tableau Server / Tableau Online, go to the content you want to embed and click the 'Share' button.

[image]

**Step 2 :** Click the "</> Embed Code" link and copy it

[image].

**Step 3 :** paste embedded code between below html body tag.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Embedded Analytics with Tableau Online</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- copy Embedded code here-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Finally,** Save the file and refresh your browser